# How to store only the changes made to a third-party repo, in a separate repo?

Tags: git, github

It seems like this would be asked, but I couldn't find anything exact. I'm using git.

I have an open source project (repo_A) on GitHub and I'd like to make a number of mostly additions to the code, but the author has no interest in merging these changes (my_repo) back into his code base (repo_A).

So I'm wondering what the process should be to get updates from repo_A and then merge my_repo changes into the updated repo_A. repo_A gets an uppdate every few weeks and my_repo gets changes daily.

I think I would like my_repo to be completely separate from repo_A and just store my changes and additions, but I'd still like to easily incorporate repo_A when it gets updated?

But then I'm not sure how to best go about all this and easily overlay my_repo onto repo_A after an updates.

Comment: I would clone repo_A to your computer. Rename origin to upstream or something. Add a new origin that points to your GitHub account.

Comment: So the proceess would be, 1) clone repo_A, 2) rename origin to upstream, 3) add new_origin which points to my github, 4) make changes,  5) commit/push my changes to new_origin.

And when it's time to update, 1) pull from "upstream", 2) then merge from new_origin, 3) make changes, 4) commit/push to new origin? Repeat.

Comment: That's what I would do